# Создать всплывающее окно с кастомным интерфейсом на Android

Tags: android, xamarin

Необходимо сделать вот похожее всплывающее полупрозрачное окно (без перехода на новую активити) в котором будет кнопка. Какой элемент лучше всего использовать? 
Думал про переопределение элемента AlertDialog, или есть более простой способ?

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-моему слишком мудрёно тут переопределять алерт диалог...
Я бы, наверно, сделал RelativeLayout, растянутый по parent и в него вставил обычный LinearLayout с необходимым полупрозрачным фоном, кнопками и всем остальным.

Тога показать это "всплывающее окно" будет просто `findViewById(R.id.relativeLayuot).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

а скрыть

`findViewById(R.id.relativeLayuot).setVisibility(View.GONE)`

обработчиками и динамическим контентом можно управлять прямо из активити.

Comment: А тулбар и статусбар? Я бы всё же использовал новое активити со стилями, так можно перекрыть и статус бар и тулбар без особых проблем, задав параметры только созданому Activity.